# Insert DataTables Data Into leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, leaflet

I'm using mysql to save my GeoInfo and using DataTables to show in table and using leaflet to show all Lat/long in map as marker
and my problem is :
instead of using mysql to put latlong of marker in leaflet , use DataTables to get data from column of table and be dynamic when i search in table on leaflet map show only data found in table.

thank you

Comment: That sounds like a description of a requirement, rather than a problem. A problem would occur when you've tried to implement your requirement, and run into some difficulty, either in coding or design or debugging etc. What specific problem are you facing with implementing your requirement, then? Also how are we supposed to suggest any useful code or other information when we can't see anything about your current implementation? We wouldn't know how to fit anything into your structure. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue, for more guidance. You can [edit] your post. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

To insert DataTables data into Leaflet, initialize a DataTable with latitude and longitude columns in your HTML. Create a Leaflet map with an initial view. Use DataTables API to fetch data and dynamically generate Leaflet markers based on the DataTable rows. Update the Leaflet map on each DataTable draw event, clearing existing markers and adding new ones with latitude and longitude information. Ensure proper CDN inclusion for Leaflet and DataTables libraries in your HTML file.